# Count total file size of many files in Windows

Tags: windows, burning, cd-r

When I want to burn a CD R with lots of files, I have to make sure the total file size in my folder doesn't exceed the capacity of the disc (680MB). In Windows are there possibilities to check the total file size of a bunch of files.

1. I put them in a folder, right-click and check the properties. But this is an annoying trial and error kind of way. Either there are too many files in the folder, or too little.
2. I watch the file size go up as I keep selecting more files, using ALT+going down button.

No. 2 is my favorite way to do it.

For some reason Windows (I still use XP) only shows the total file size of 100 selected files. When you select more than 100 files, no file size information appears any more. Is there way, a trick, an app, to work around this problem?

Comment: Just do a properties of the folder instead of the selected files inside. My burning software (Nero) shows me how much space is left as I add files to be burned.

Comment: **When you select more than 100 files, no file size information appears any more** <---That does not happen here, at all, ever on XP?? I just tested it again. I can select 1000+ files of terrabyte of size and both the simple status bar, and the properties show the size. I wonder if it could have to do with the "previewing" stuff which takes forever and I have turned off? or single corrupt file in combo with previewing junk?

Answer (score 1):

If you select all the files you want to put onto your disc, then **right click**, click Properties, you will see the total size of all your selected files.

Comment: @Moab Wizlog bolded that chunk. ;)

Comment: D'oh, look at the time stamp!

Comment: @techie007 so what?  should I not have?  (btw, Is my answer good?)

Comment: It's good but short. I'd add a bit on adding/removing items from a selection.